# Multithreaded Port Scanner

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, python-2.7

Yes, yes I know I could just use nmap but I want to try this out myself.

I'm trying to write a threaded script to find open ports on a target IP address. This is what I have right now:

```
import socket, Queue
from threading import Thread


print "Target to scan: "
targetIP = raw_input("> ")
print "Number of threads: "
threads = int(raw_input("> "))


q = Queue.Queue()

# Fill queue with port numbers
for port in range(1, 1025):
    q.put(port)


def scan(targetIP, port):
    try:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.settimeout(4)
        result = s.connect_ex((targetIP, port))
        if result == 0:
            print 'Port {0} is open'.format(port)
        s.close
        q.task_done()



while q.full:
    for i in range(threads):
        port = q.get()
        t = Thread(target=scan, args =(targetIP, port))
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
```

However I have a few issues:

1) When I run this as is, it will iterate through the port queue but then just hang, never breaking from the `while` loop even though the queue empties.

2) If I add a print line to `scan` to see whats happening, basically add a "Scanning port X" line in the beginning and a `print result` line at the end, stdout gets flooded with the "Scanning port" line for all ports in the queue, and THEN the result lines get printed. Meaning, it looks like currently the script is not waiting for `result` to get a value, and just continue iterating on as if it had.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `Meaning, it looks like currently the script is not waiting for result to get a value, and just continue iterating on as if it had.` Meaning, the script is running in multiple threads rather than sequentially? Isn't that what you wanted in the first place?

Comment: The wait is until `q.full` is false. You're not calling the function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems here, the first is:

```
while q.full:
```

Presumably you meant to *call* the function:

```
while q.full():
```

But you have an infinite queue (you created it with no maxsize), so it's never full; so if you make that change, it won't call scan() at all.

Assuming you fix this in some other way (e.g., using `q.empty()`), what happens if `range(threads)` does not evenly divide the items in the queue?  For instance, suppose you use 3 threads and put port numbers 1, 2, 3, and 4 into `q`.  You'll call `q.get()` three times (getting 1, 2, and 3) in the first trip through the outer `while`, and then call it three times again in the second trip—but it only has one more value in it, `4`, so the call to `q.get()` after that will wait for someone to execute a `q.put()`, and you will get stuck.

You need to rewrite the logic, in other words.

Edit: same problem with `s.close` vs `s.close()`.  Others addressed the whole pool-of-threads aspect. @Blender's version, using `multiprocessing`, is a lot simpler since `multiprocessing` takes care of that for you.

Answer (score 4):

Your actual question has already been answered by a few people, so here's an alternative solution with `multiprocessing.Pool` instead of `threading`:

```
import socket

from multiprocessing import Pool

def scan(arg):
    target_ip, port = arg

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.settimeout(2)

    try:
        sock.connect((target_ip, port))
        sock.close()

        return port, True
    except (socket.timeout, socket.error):
        return port, False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    target_ip = raw_input('Target IP: ')
    num_procs = int(raw_input('Number of processes: '))

    ports = range(1, 1025)
    pool = Pool(processes=num_procs)

    for port, status in pool.imap_unordered(scan, [(target_ip, port) for port in ports]):
        print port, 'is', 'open' if status else 'closed'
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your code. First, the while loop continues until `q.full`, which is a function, is falsy. But actually there's no need to loop in your main thread.

I would add sentinel values to the end of the queue, one per worker thread. When the worker thread gets a sentinel, it quits its processing loop. This way you don't have to daemonize the Threads.

So you code should be like:

- put ports into queue
- put sentinels into queue
- start the desired number of threads, have them take ports from the queue and process them, put the results in another queue
- wait for the threads to terminate, calling `t.join()` on the workers
- use the results

Answer (score 0):

Well you have to know that by just iterating through the numbers in the range of the number of threads and executing the thread, you don't keep the number of desired threads. It just loops 4 times, creates 4 threads, loops again and enters the another same loop and creates another 4 without being sure that those 4 have finish their task, so you get that flood of messages when you put prints in scan function.

You would have to wait for the childs to finish at the end of the while body section.

I think:

```
threading.wait()
```

does the thing.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
import socket
import threading
from queue import Queue

print_lock = threading.Lock()

target = 'pythonprogramming.net'

def portscan(port):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        con = s.connect((target,port))
        with print_lock:
            print('port',port,'is open!')
        con.close()
    except:
        pass

def threader():
    while True:
        worker = q.get()
        portscan(worker)
        q.task_done()

q = Queue()

for x in range(30):
    t = threading.Thread(target=threader)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()


for worker in range(1,10000):
    q.put(worker)

q.join()
```

Comment: Your answer should contains an explanation of your code and a description how it solves the problem.